# Changing the color of a Clarity toggle switch

Tags: css, angular, clarity

I have a Angular project with .Net core and I'm using Clarity as well, I was wondering if there is a way to change the color of a Clarity toggle switch?

**my code that I've tried so far which was not working:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" formControlName="validateAll" Color="red" clrToggle />
```

---

```
 <input type="checkbox" formControlName="validateAll" style="background-color:red"  clrToggle />
```

---

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="validateAll" style="color:red"  clrToggle />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom class to the wrapping div, change the styles to the input as it's said in the [documentation](https://clarity.design/documentation/toggle-switches#css-component)

The toggle switch is created by using `::before` and `::after` on the `label` tag. So if you name your wrapper class for the div `custom-styles` then your css should look like this:

```
.custom-styles input[type=checkbox]+label::before {
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;   
}
```

**and for checked**

```
.custom-styles input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: red;   
}
```